# Can I define a new type in julia that acts like primitive data type?

Tags: julia, primitive-types

I need to know if there is any way to define a new type in Julia that acts like primitive data type, for example:

```
struct test
 att1::MyType
end
```

Let's suppose that my `MyType` is only from 1 to 10. So if I make an instance like this:

`test1=test(11)` it should give me an error.

I can guess there is an easier way to do this, but I need to extend MyType more than just from 1 to 10.

Comment: I'm not sure primitive types are the way to go here. You have to specify a number of bits N that aligns to a multiple of bytes (8, 16, 24, etc), and all such integer types have 2^N values (that cycle via overflow). It's not going to align with arbitrary limits like [1,10]. It'll be complicated to reimplement arithmetic for a type to cycle [1,10] like the primitive `Int8` cycles [-128,127]. If you want to implement arbitrary limits, then you would need a parametric type. It'd be easier to use limit checks and modulo on existing types.

Comment: Agreed with BatWannaBe: you can do "low level" things without primitive types. For example, look at how Julia implements complex numbers: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/complex.jl. Those are very low-level but no use of `primitive`. Just use an inner constructor: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/constructors/#man-inner-constructor-methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to define primitive types is described [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#Primitive-Types) in the Julia Manual.

In the InlineStrings.jl package you have an excellent demo code [here](https://github.com/JuliaData/InlineStrings.jl/blob/main/src/InlineStrings.jl) how you can define such types in practice with custom constructors (which I assume you want as I guess you want to perform checking for valid range of arguments when you run the constructor of your type).